# How can I change the permissions of a mounted window share?

Tags: permissions, ntfs

I have a Windows partition which I can easily access using Nautilus.

It automatically gets mounted at `/media`

```
deel@ubuntu:/media$ ls -l
total 16
drwx------ 1 deel deel 16384 2011-11-16 10:33 New Volume  

deel@ubuntu:/media$ sudo chmod 755 New\ Volume/  

deel@ubuntu:/media$ ls -l  

total 16
drwx------ 1 deel deel 16384 2011-11-16 10:33 New Volume
```

If you notice in above even after changing permissions the permissions have not changed.
What could be the reason and how can I change the permissions?

Here is my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none            swap    loop,sw         0       0
~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions for a windows share are determined at mount time, and cannot changed at run time.

If you want different permissions, you have to manually mount the partition and provide options to the command to give **all** files and directories the required permissions.

Also, you can set the permissions in `/etc/fstab`, that in addition to the `noauto` option should allow to mount with nautilus with option determined in `fstab`.

The command could be

```
sudo mkdir -p "/media/New Volume"
sudo mount -o uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022 /dev/sd1 "/media/New Volume"
```

where `0022` is the complement to `755 = rwxr-xr-x`, `/dev/sda1` is the windows partition, and `1000` is your numeric user id and group id.

Comment: Here is my /etc/fstab file
`# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>  
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
  
  /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
  
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none            swap    loop,sw         0       0
~                                                                                      `